# JQuery dialog title bar and close button not visible

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jQuery-UI dialog. It openes normally, but after opening  title bar and close button are not visible.

[image]

Title bar and close button should look like this:

[image]

I really don't understand why they are hidden. Close button is functioning normally, although it's hidden.

My source code is [here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/7368254c0a28c903bed4ac3325158c9f?editors=1010)

Code for opening dialog is quite simple:

```
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  },
  title: "This is my title"
});

$( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Source files:

Scripts:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap.min.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/jqBootstrapValidation.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/json3.min.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/jquery.cookie.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap-datepicker.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap-timepicker.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/common.js

Styles:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap.min.css
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/datepicker3.css
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap-timepicker.css
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/common.css
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/bootstrap-custom.css

Comment: Have you got any CSS that might be overriding it?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Can you post the full source code? So we can see it all and test it ourselves to see what is going wrong. Or you can just inspect element it to see styles on the right side

Comment: This is all that I have. Source files are visible under 'JS' and 'CSS'. Or have you meant something else?

Comment: I've added source files (scripts and styles) to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was that I was using jQuery-UI and bootstrap at the same time. Bootstrap overrided some jQuery-UI classes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be considered as quick fix.

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar{background-color:#c2c2c2;}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
  background-image: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aui/6.0.1/aui/css/icons/aui-icon-close.png);
  z-index:999999;
}
```

But at times this might work.

Answer (score 0):

The CDN of jquery you were using are blocking the ui-images

> s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/images/ui-bg_glass_75_ffffff_1x400.png
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

Use the jquery-ui css and js from another CDN, example:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui

Comment: I don't think this is the reason. Source files are opening normally if I copy - paste link in the browser.

Comment: Yes but the image URLs used internally by jquery are forbidden, I updated them to use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css and the dialog opened as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem in my production server (in production files are loaded into server, not from CDN). And I can not change version.

Comment: Are you getting the same error in console on your server?

Comment: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/images/ui-bg_glass_75_ffffff_1x400.png, https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/554096/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png both these links are giving 403 error, how come they are openning with you?

Comment: no, I don't have the same error in production server. Only title bar and close button are not showing.

Comment: Do you think those two images can affect title bar / close button visibility?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144433/discussion-between-frenkyb-and-kad).

Comment: Sorry, am in an environment that blocks the chat through proxy ;(

Comment: To answer your question, yes, one of them is the sprite, holding the X icon, and the other is the background